# My page isn't being responsive and looks odd in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

Here's the web page in question:

https://www.sunnyenterprises.biz/del/

It looks perfectly fine in browser. I set the div heights in pixels, in the stylesheet. But in mobile, it looks odd. How can I fix my CSS to make it look responsive in mobile as well?

Also, there's a problem with the mobile menu, it doesn't disappear, the dropdown menu stays there even after I clicked a link on it. You can see it if you browse the site on a mobile device.

I have tried adjusting the DIV heights, but I couldn't get it right. Also, I have no clue why the mobile menu won't disappear and is sticking.

Here's my CSS code.

```
.subtext {
    color:#999999;
    font-size:18px;
    !important
}
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000D28;
}
.navbar-inverse{
    border: none;
    background: rgba(1, 32, 96, 0.93);
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle{
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle i{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.navbar-inverse a{
    margin-left: 46px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand{
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #F0C12D;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
    color: #F0C12D;
}
.container .iphone{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 900px;
}
.container .margin-div{
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: #000D28;
}
.margin-div h1{
    color:#F0C12D;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.margin-div a{
    text-align: center;
}
.margin-div p{
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.margin-div p>a{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.del-rio{
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 950px;
    background: #fff;
}
.shamrath{
    width: 100%;
    height: 950px;
    background: #fff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    shamrath {
    height: 400px;
    }
}
.container .margin-div-section{
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: #fff;
}
.margin-div-section h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.margin-div-section a{
    text-align: center;
}
.margin-div-section h2{
    color:#333333;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.margin-div-section p>a{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.margin-div-section .ipad{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 700px;
}
.silversand{
    width: 100%;
    height: 880px;
    background: #121117;
}
.concrete{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #121117;
}
.container .margin-div-section-macbook{
    background: #121117;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.margin-div-section-macbook .macbook{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1500px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.margin-div-section-macbook h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}
.margin-div-section-macbook a{
    text-align: center;
}
.margin-div-section-macbook p{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white
}
.margin-div-section-macbook p>a{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
}
.section-shop{
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}
.img-row{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}


.carousel-inner {
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want? But try to debug your code, we can't do it for you. P.s. don't see any issue for the menu hamburger and i see your site with columns .

Answer (score 0):

You have missed (.) for class `.shamrath` please add (.) before `shamrath`

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .shamrath {
      height: 400px;
    }
}
```

to hide menu use below Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(){
    $("#menu").removeClass(".show");
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The 'shamrath' section still has a huge white space below the content when viewing in mobile.

Comment: sorry you missed (.) for class shamrath updated my answer please check

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot to add the . before shamrath, to state it as a class.

Comment: Yes thank you it works now. Thanks so much. What about the mobile menu? How do I get it to disappear after I have clicked a link?

Comment: for menu you need to call collapse fuction again onclick on menu link..

Answer (score 0):

To hide the menu on click use below jQuery in your code.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(){
    $("#menu").removeClass("in show");
  });
});
```

And, to adjust height of div in mobile screen you can try below CSS code.

CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
.silversand, .del-rio, .shamrath {
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed the div height problem. I added that javascript but the menu still wont disappear.

Comment: I forgot to link to the jquery lib file, sorry. Its working perfectly now. Thanks so much.